# Configure ASP.NET Core authentication middleware to always return 401 when Authorization header is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I created a default ASP.NET Core (2.1) empty web application, and added JWT bearer authentication. The `Startup.cs` class looks like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            var keyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(Constants.JwtSecretKey);
            var signinKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = Constants.Audience,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = Constants.Issuer,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signinKey
            };
        });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The controller looks like this:

```cs
[Route("values")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
    }
}
```

I would like my endpoint to return a 401 HTTP status code when the Authorization header is present but invalid (with an error message containing the failure reason) - but NOT when the header is missing. Is it possible to configure the middleware in such a way?

I tried fiddling with the OnAuthenticationFailed event from JwtBearerEvents, but couldn't get anything done with it.

```cs
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
{
    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        // Not fired when the Authorization header is "Bearer foo",
        // but fired when the header is "Bearer foo.bar.baz"
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents?view=aspnetcore-2.2#properties), JwtBearerEvents only support the below 4 kind of event

1. OnAuthenticationFailed(this one only triggered after Token failed to be Authenticated, in your case I think you need a validation instead of authentication)
2. OnChallenge
3. OnMessageReceived
4. OnTokenValidated(this one however only triggered after Token is successfully validated, that's why I think it does not work for your case)

What you want should be something like OnTokenValidateFailed but it is not there, one workaround would be register the OnMessageReceived events and try to validate token there

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.Audience = "api1";
                    options.Events=new JwtBearerEvents(){
                        OnMessageReceived  =context=>{
                            var header =context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                            //Your validation logic here
                            //if validate failed
                            //{                           
                            //context.Response.StatusCode=401; 
                            //}                          
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };
                });
```

This way you can validate token by yourself however this approach might not short circuit the whole request pipeline and might conflict with other middleware(Not tested tested with other middleware but I assume this might happen)

Another workround would be like below

Add below code in your Config of start.cs in your API project

```
app.Use(async(context,next)=>{
                var authHeader=context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
                //Your validation here
                if(validation failed)
                {
                  context.Response.StatusCode=401;
                  await context.Response.CompleteAsync();
                }
                else{
                await next.Invoke();}
            });
```

Add this before UseAuthenticate to overwrite default Authernticate middleware

First workaournd would trigger when it comes to JwtBearerToken authenticate while the second one will always be triggered since it is registered in the asp.net core middleware pipeline, so it is your choice to decidede to use which one

Comment: I always assume I'm doing something wrong when I resort to writing directly to the `Response` object in an existing middleware extension point (such as in your 1st workaround). With the way ASP.NET middlewares work, it's always been more trouble than it's worth, causing exceptions very difficult to reproduce (e.g. when there is a very specific scenario where some other component in the pipeline already started to write to the response at this point).

Comment: The first is modifiying http response inside the auth middleware so your concern do make sense, however you can put the second one after userouting and before useauthentication, this way you can short circuit the request as soon as the token is found invalied.

Comment: You're right, that's why I specified "such as in your 1st workaround" :) On the other hand, the 2nd workaround would result in performing the JWT validation twice in case the token is valid (once in the custom middleware, once in the .NET authentication middleware). Also, are you sure the code should invoke the `next` delegate when the validation fails? Nonetheless, I get the idea and it should work.

Comment: I edit my comment and yes invoke.next should not be called after validation failed.

Comment: You can also try App.UseWhen to better optimize the performance that only valide the Token when there is token presented, see samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#branch-the-middleware-pipeline)